# Please specify an authentication passphrase for smpd:

Tags: c, mpi

I recently use MPICH2 to write parallel code.
But when I run `wmpiexec.exe` in `bin\` I received this:

> Please specify an authentication passphrase for smpd:

what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your username and password, (your windows username and pass) using:

`StartMenu->All Programs->MPICH2->wmpiregister.exe`

Also ensure that you installed the smpd in Administrator mode.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing this same issue, but simply wmpiregister.exe does not work.

So I followed the following steps and it worked:

1- Disable your Firewall (or modify the rules)

2- Open an admin command prompt by right-clicking on the command prompt icon selecting run as administrator.

3- Type the following commands on the prompt in sequence:

```
smpd -install 
mpiexec -remove 
mpiexec -register  (this will ask for user name and password, enter it and confirm it)
mpiexec -validate (Must return SUCCESS) 
smpd -status
```

The last command will return

> 'smpd running on hostname'

Every thing should work fine now.